# pushing bash history to github regularly

Tags: linux, git, bash, ubuntu, github

I want to push the bash history to my github account regularly,say everyday I will push the history to github, how do I do it. Any heads up. Is it possbile?
The bash history file should be renamed to the current data-time. So that I can track. In spite of having a local bash history I prefer to have in github also.

Thanks a lot

Comment: why do you want to track a file with git and at the same time rename (i guess you mean "copy") it with a timestamp? git already tracks history (including timestamps of the commits)

Comment: @umlaeute I am not trying to track my code's history I am trying to track my entire bash history, makes difference bro :)

Comment: no it doesn't make a difference

Comment: I am speaking only my bash history and nothing else. git doesnt track my bash history !!!

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer to**

> The bash history file should be renamed to the current data-time.

```
cp -avi "$HISTFILE" "$HISTFILE".$( date -r "$HISTFILE" --rfc-3339=sec | tr ' ' T )
```

This will copy your current bash history file to one with a timestamp suffix taken from your bash history file's last modification date.